# php preg_match get everything after match in string

Tags: php, preg-match, request-uri

Looking for how to get the complete string in a URI, after the away?to=

My code:

```
if (isset($_SERVER[REQUEST_URI])) {
    $goto = $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
}

if (preg_match("/to=(.+)/", $goto, $goto_url)) {

$link = "<a href='{$goto_url[1]}' target='_blank'>{$goto_url[1]}</a>";
```

The original link is:

```
https://domain.com/away?to=http://www.zdf.de/ZDFmediathek#/beitrag/video/2162504/Verschw%C3%B6rung-gegen-die-Freiheit-%281%29
```

.. but my code is cutting the string after the **away?to=** to only

```
http://www.zdf.de/ZDFmediathek
```

You know the fix for this preg_match function to allow really every character following the **away?to=** ??

**UPDATE:**

Found out, that `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` or `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` is already cutting the original URL. Do you know why and how to prevent that?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you don't just use `$_GET['to']`?

Comment: Tested. `$goto_url[1]` contains the full needed url.

Comment: You must check `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` not `REQUEST_URI`

Comment: @Deadooshka : Tested with QUERY_STRING, same result, I'm not receiving the full original URL after the ?to .... $goto is already cutted :-(

Comment: Browser not send the hash part (after the `#` symbol) of the URL to the server. It must be URL-escaped (url-encoded).

Comment: I see, that's the important info! But how can I then get the recent URL in general when it contains such symbols? Is there any $_SERVER for that?

Comment: The unescaped hash is a client side stuff, so the server can't get it.

Answer (score 3):

try use  `(.*)` to get all after `to=`

```
$str = 'away?to=dfkhgkjdshfgkhldsflkgh';
preg_match("/to=(.*)/", $str, $goto_url);
echo $goto_url[1]; //dfkhgkjdshfgkhldsflkgh
```

Comment: Tried this already, same results, its cutting the url when # is included in the url.

Comment: it's working you can include # in string for try or try use urldecode()

Comment: Thanks, You saved my time brother.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of extracting the URL with regex from the request URI you can just get it from the $_GET array:

```
$link = "<a href='{$_GET['to']}' target='_blank'>{$_GET['to']}</a>";
```

Comment: it's clear, but 'to' may contain incorrect URL due to probably unescaped special symbols.

Comment: Danke, but try this with the original url I gave, it's getting cutted as well, echo $link;

Comment: Well, as other people already advised, encode the url properly in the preceding page.

Comment: I know it's an old issue, I ran into it searching for a regex.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-input.php
Never use GET/POST variables directly.